# how to group by letter and put in same letter size

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a LINQ query to group elements by the first letter of the word

```
var res = from sign in all
          group sign by sign.first_letter into grp
          select grp;
```

But when I have `apple` and `August`, I'll get two groups. Group `a` and group `A`. How to put them in the same group ?

Comment: I would *strongly* suggest inserting some line breaks here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could group by the lower case letter, using either [Char.ToLower](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhef7hhe.aspx) or [String.ToLower](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78f86at.aspx), depending on the type:

```
var res = from sign in all 
          group sign by Char.ToLower(sign.first_letter) 
          into grp 
          select grp;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this (grouping by `lowercase` letter) -

```
var res = from sign in all group sign by sign.first_letter.ToLower()
               into grp select grp;
```